# neo4j stop command time out

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

The error that I got is

```
Neo4j (pid 11389) took more than 120 seconds to stop.
```

I installed neo4j like this:

```
wget -O - https://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
echo 'deb http://debian.neo4j.org/repo stable/' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neo4j.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y neo4j
sudo echo "NEO4J_ULIMIT_NOFILE=60000" >> /etc/default/neo4j
```

However, when I started neo4j service and then try to stop `sudo service neo4j stop`. The following problem occurs

```
Stopping Neo4j........................................................................................................................ failed to stop
Neo4j (pid 11389) took more than 120 seconds to stop.
Please see /var/log/neo4j/neo4j.log for details.
```

And here is the log:

```
nohup: ignoring input
2016-11-11 19:48:26.913+0000 INFO  Starting...
2016-11-11 19:48:27.304+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on localhost:7687.
2016-11-11 19:48:29.655+0000 INFO  Started.
2016-11-11 19:48:30.384+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
2016-11-11 19:49:07.230+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
2016-11-11 19:49:07.237+0000 INFO  Stopping...
```

More in Debug.log:

```
BatchingMultipleIndexPopulator{activeTasks=0, executor=java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@82bd3a4[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], batchedUpdates = [6164 updates], queuedUpdates = 0}
2016-11-13 15:49:07.886+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.a.i.IndexPopulationJob] Shutting down executor.
BatchingMultipleIndexPopulator{activeTasks=1, executor=java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@82bd3a4[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], batchedUpdates = [], queuedUpdates = 0}
2016-11-13 15:50:10.248+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Check Pointing triggered by scheduler for time threshold [54]:  Starting check pointing...
2016-11-13 15:50:10.249+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Check Pointing triggered by scheduler for time threshold [54]:  Starting store flush...
2016-11-13 15:50:47.813+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.f.CommunityFacadeFactory] Shutdown started
2016-11-13 15:50:47.813+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.f.CommunityFacadeFactory] Database is now unavailable
```

What did I do wrong? I do not want to kill neo4j by `kill -9` every time.

Comment: Is there anything in `debug.log` or `messages.log`? Were there any running queries when you tried stopping Neo4j?

Comment: There is something in `debug.log` I don't see `messages.log` in the `logs` folder.

Comment: I had a similar issue but what I did was to set a timeout **dbms.transaction.timeout.**  when I noticed I had a query that was running  too long.